# Why Google place api returning empty results for nearby doctor?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am working on a project where I need to find nearby doctors. I have implemented google place api in this case but the same is not returning any doctor nearby in any location.

Here is the URL I have used for the HTTP call

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=12.71942373,77.70221857&radius=500&type=doctor&key=AIzaSyDgAdvN36L-7-32Sp9Rk5ytYiLuWBoGTT4
```

I haave tried changing the co ordinates but then again the value is empty. I do have the api enabled in the console.

Please let me know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please give a reason for down voteing as the problem is genuine and I'm definitely not faking

Comment: The result is: `ZERO_RESULTS`, meaning there are no doctors in range.

Comment: this is working api and returning many result, if put in browser with my location

Comment: Well I have tried with other coordinates from bangalore and none of those works. I'm pretty much sure in bangalore there are doctors

Comment: @devendra would you mind sharing the location so that I verify the same

Comment: 19.448558, 72.802661 i tested with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are receiving here is that there are no doctors in your area based on the radius you gave. I altered the `radius` to **50000**, and the query returned results. So your query would be this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=12.71942373,77.70221857&radius=50000&type=doctor&key=AIzaSyDgAdvN36L-7-32Sp9Rk5ytYiLuWBoGTT4
```

Although there might be doctors in the are you are specifying, these may not be registered with Google, to the Places API would not be displaying them.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Okay but I tried the coordinates of the place where doctors are there , I have checked the same using google map but why won't it reflect here? Any suggestion would be really helpful

Comment: Maybe the data Google Maps is using is not yet realeased to the public. So it won't display the information in your map.